# How to load external AMD module using Typescript 1.5?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I'm using VS2015 and I've created a TypeScript HTML application.
I also made the simplest possible external module, like this.

```
export class MyClass {
    public Test(): string {
        return "Erik";
    };

    constructor() {
    };
};
```

Then in my app.ts file i wrote the following.

```
import E = require('./Erik');

window.onload = () => {
    let c: E.MyClass = new E.MyClass();
    alert(c.Test());
};
```

Using F12 dubugging in Chrome I can see this error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

What am I missing? I have made sure that AMD moduletype is selected in the project settings and a Erik.js file is created when compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to use a module loader library that works with AMD modules.

For example, you could include [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) in your application, then do something along these lines:

```
<script data-main="scripts/app" src="scripts/require.min.js"></script>
```

Where `data-main` is the path to `app.js`.